# python pyserial writing more than once to serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am writing and reading from the same serial port. Here is what problem is:

When I write to serial port one after another, like in the code below:

```
import serial
import array


rec = serial.Serial()
trans = serial.Serial()

rec.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
rec.baudrate = 9600
rec.timeout = 0.5
rec.open()

trans.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
trans.baudrate = 9600
trans.timeout = 0.5
trans.open()


if trans.isOpen():
   trans.write("\xFE\x1D\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xE2")    
   trans.write("\xFE\x1D\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xE3")

while rec.isOpen():

response = rec.readline()


etc. etc. etc
```

As long as while loop turns, I keep reading only the first sent string. Also I tried to send data just after the while loop: (I did not delete the if statement)

```
while rec.isOpen():
    trans.write("\x00\x00")
    response = rec.readline()
```

What I read from the serial port is still:
   "\xFE\x1D\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xE2"

I cannot send any other data other than the first one. Why is it happening? What should I do?

note: Also in the while loop I tried to read twice:
    response = rec.readline()
    response = rec.readline()

This time, when I print the array that I read, it prints [] which means I cannot read anything.
Regards

EDIT: Now I used two different usb ports ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1 to check if my problem is related to that situation. But seems like nothing is wrong with writing and reading from the same port.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be port misconfiguration. You have to set proper values

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=???,
    stopbits=???,
    bytesize=???)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not see newlines, so you should try with rec.read(bytes) or finish lines with \0d\0a or something.

See http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#readline

Comment: hmm, I used read(bytes) it did not solve my problem but did not try your second suggestion. it may be the solution to the problem that I explained however it is not a durable solution for me. because when my code is finished, I will not be sending data to port with this code. I will have a sensor which will send data and I will read it and it does not send any kind of EOL data. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that, my sensor data's length will no be fix.